# Use FileStream Like StreamWriter (Write, WriteLine)

Tags: c#, filestream, flush

I want to use [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2), because [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) has [`.Flush(true)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2) witch writes cached data on stream into disk, but when I changed [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2), there are many errors in my code, because [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2)does not have `.Write()` and `.WriteLine()` methods

How can I use [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2)Like [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2)? I want call `.WriteLine(string _)` on [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2)but it's not exists. Is there any way to add this method?

Comment: Use the [StreamWriter(Stream) constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_).  Which lets you pass the FileStream you like.

Comment: @HansPassant: Then I must call Flush() on StreamWriter and Flush(true) on FileStream, am I right?

Comment: No, FileStream.Flush(bool) is special, StreamWriter does not use it.  You get to choose between setting the StreamWriter's AutoFlush to true or calling Flush yourself.

Comment: @elgonzo, flushing on StreamWriter, invokes .Flush(true) on FileStream? Argument 'true' means flush to disk (physical hard disk), not the operating system's buffer!

Comment: It does not, elgonzo's comment is misleading.

Comment: Oh, damn. Hans is right. I overlooked that you specifically asked about `Flush(true)`. Calling `Flush()` is equivalent to calling `Flush(false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) methods like this

```
    using System.IO;
    ...
    public static class MyExtensionClass
    {
        public static void Write(this FileStream fs, object value)
        {
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(value + "");
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
        public static void WriteLine(this FileStream fs, object value = null)
        {
            fs.Write(value + "\r\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this byte[] array will be clean after the function exit? I'm doubt, because there is a "new" keyword